# how can I bypass captcha while Signing into google or Microsoft with selenium automation?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, google-signin, recaptcha, captcha

Whenever I try to Sign In to Google or Microsoft using Selenium It can not handle the CAPTCHA and the testScript failed. if I handle CAPTCHA manually, then the testcase further start running and passed. I want to bypass the CAPTCHA  or any solution to handle the CAPTCHA in Automation.